# Initialization of list with for_each to random variables

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

I'm trying to initialize a list to random integers using a for_each and a lambda function. I'm new to boost.lambda functions so I may be using this incorrectly but the following code is producing a list of the same numbers. Every time I run it the number is different but everything in the list is the same:

```
srand(time(0));

theList.resize(MaxListSize);

for_each(theList.begin(), theList.end(), _1 = (rand() % MaxSize));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boost lambda will evaluate `rand` before the functor is made. You need to `bind` it, so it's evaluated at lambda evaluation time:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp> // for bind
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    namespace bl = boost::lambda;
    typedef std::vector<int> int_vec;

    static const size_t MaxListSize = 10;
    static const int MaxSize = 20;

    int_vec theList;
    theList.resize(MaxListSize);

    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(0)));
    std::for_each(theList.begin(), theList.end(),
                    bl::_1 = bl::bind(std::rand) % MaxSize);

    std::for_each(theList.begin(), theList.end(), std::cout << bl::_1 << ' ' );
}
```

This works as expected.

However, the *correct* solution is to use `generate_n`. Why make a bunch of 0's just to overwrite them?

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    namespace bl = boost::lambda;
    typedef std::vector<int> int_vec;

    static const size_t MaxListSize = 10;
    static const int MaxSize = 20;

    int_vec theList;
    theList.reserve(MaxListSize); // note, reserve

    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(0)));
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(theList), MaxListSize,
                        bl::bind(std::rand) % MaxSize);

    std::for_each(theList.begin(), theList.end(), std::cout << bl::_1 << ' ' );
}
```

Comment: Ahh, nice one that's a great response.